# Unknown status type returned by go-git

Tags: git, go, go-git

I am trying to get the status of a file checked in a `git` repo using `go-git` [library](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-git/go-git/v5@v5.1.0?tab=overview).

So I am running this code snippet:

```
    var status = git.Status{}
    var fileStatus *git.FileStatus
    fileStatus = status.File(fullPathToApp)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", fileStatus.Staging)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", fileStatus.Worktree)
```

All I get is two `63` s getting printed out

```
63
63
```

What does this correspond to in terms of git status?

I cannot seem to make a direct relation to the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-git/go-git/v5@v5.1.0?tab=doc#StatusCode) of the `StatusCode`.

btw the file pointed to by `fullPathToApp` is clean, i.e. it is tracked and committed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to open the repository and worktree first

```
    r, err := git.PlainOpen(pathToRepo)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    w, err := r.Worktree()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

After that fetch the status

```
    ws, err := w.Status()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

To get the status you only need to enter the filename that is in the repository

```
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", ws.File("filename").Staging)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", ws.File("filename").Worktree)
```

> I cannot seem to make a direct relation to the documentation of the StatusCode.

The status code returned is a byte

63 = ?

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. After following your example I am able to print `?` twice; the problem is that according to [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-git/go-git/v5@v5.1.0?tab=doc#StatusCode) `?` --> `Untracked`. However the file is properly checked in to `git` and unmodified; why am I getting the question mark as status code that corresponds to `Untracked` ?

Comment: When I try to print the status, as in `fmt.Printf("%#v\n", ws)` for some reason I get an empty struct `git.Status{}` for what that matters

Comment: My list of remotes seems empty as well when printing my repository `&git.Repository{Storer:(*filesystem.Storage)(0xc000492780), r:map[string]*git.Remote{}, wt:(*chroot.ChrootHelper)(0xc000450ae0)}`; am I missing any step? auth probably?

Comment: It's a private repo btw

Comment: Hi @pkaramol, judging by your initial question, I'd say these extra points you mention come *after* you've resolved your initial issue, would you agree ? In that case, you can investigate more thoroughly what happens on your side, and perhaps ask another question if you still have issues. Cheers

Comment: You are right; accepted this answer and proceeded with opening [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62738651/go-git-reports-a-file-as-untracked-while-it-should-be-unmodified) question.