# go-git reports a file as Untracked while it should be Unmodified

Tags: git, go, go-git

I am trying to check the status of a particular file in a `git` repo using `go-git` [library](https://github.com/go-git/go-git).

This is the code I am attempting to run:

```
    repo, err := git.PlainOpen(fullPathToRepo)
    if err != nil {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("ERROR: Unable to open repository %s\n%s", fullPathToRepo, err)
    }

    workTree, err := repo.Worktree()
    if err != nil {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("ERROR: Unable to open worktree for repository %s\n%s", fullPathToRepo, err)
    }
    workTreeStatus, err := workTree.Status()
    if err != nil {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("ERROR: Unable to retrieve worktree status for repository %s\n%s", fullPathToRepo, err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", workTreeStatus.File("releases/filename").Worktree)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", workTreeStatus.File("/Users/panteliskaramolegkos/myrepo/filename/releases/faros.yaml").Worktree)
    return workTreeStatus.IsClean(), nil
```

i.e. I am attempting to use both the full as also the relevant (to the repo) path to the file I want to check.

In both cases what is printed out is the following:

```
`?`
`?`
```

According to the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-git/go-git/v5@v5.1.0?tab=doc#StatusCode) however, this corresponds to an `Untracked` file.

The specific file is properly committed and checked in.

Why am I getting the wrong status code?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

```golang
var fileStatusMapping = map[git.StatusCode]string{
        git.Unmodified:         "",
        git.Untracked:          "Untracked",
        git.Modified:           "Modified",
        git.Added:              "Added",
        git.Deleted:            "Deleted",
        git.Renamed:            "Renamed",
        git.Copied:             "Copied",
        git.UpdatedButUnmerged: "Updated",
}

func (r *Repo) FileStatus(filename string) (string, string, error) {
        w, err := r.worktree()
        if err != nil {
                return "", "", err
        }
        s, err := w.Status()
        if err != nil {
                return "", "", err
        }
        if s != nil {
                var untracked bool
                if s.IsUntracked(filename) {
                        untracked = true
                }
                fileStatus := s.File(filename)
                if !untracked && fileStatus.Staging == git.Untracked &&
                        fileStatus.Worktree == git.Untracked {
                        fileStatus.Staging = git.Unmodified
                        fileStatus.Worktree = git.Unmodified
                }
                return fileStatusMapping[fileStatus.Staging], fileStatusMapping[fileStatus.Worktree], nil
        }
        return "", "", nil
}
```

NOTE: `s.IsUntracked()` called before `s.File()` on purpose